# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation: How to apply two animations at once

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, cgaffinetransform

I have a view which I would like to transform in two ways. First I'd like to move it on its y-axis. Then, I'd like to zoom in on it.

However, when I use the following code, the object is first moved and then moved back to its original position while being zoomed.

Is there a way to apply the two transformation at once without cancelling the first?

Sorry if this is basic, but any help would be very much appreciated!

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                 currentCover.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0-keyboardTop+35);


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                 [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{ 

                 [currentCover setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1.3, 1.3)];


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { }
 ];



                 }
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should multiply one transform by the other. Each transform (scale and translate) are transform matrices. To combine them, simply multiple one by the other before using it. The order of the multiplication determines the order that the tranforms are applied

Answer (score 1):

I'd similar issue where my view moves back to original position.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1) of `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` reads "it constructs a new translation matrix from x and y values that specify how much to move the origin." I don't think it applies actual transformation.

I think you'd rather apply translation by calling `CGAffineTransformTranslate()`. At least it works for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Here we are creating the two changes (CGAffineTransform's) you want to do together, and apply the transformation to the view.

```
       CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0-keyboardTop+35);
        CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);

    [UIView animateWithDuration: animationDuration
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             currentCover.transform = transform;
                         }completion:^(BOOL finished){
      }];
```